# What is the probability that each person ends up with EXACTLY one of the 3 spades when the cards are dealt?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A deck of cards has 24 cards remaining,  with 3 spades and 21 non-spades.
>   I am going to deal them equally among 3 people (8 cards each)
>   What is the probability that each person ends up with EXACTLY one of the 3 spades when the cards are dealt?

I know the odds of having at least one spade in each hand are 1/3, but this is different than the odds of each person having exactly one of the three available spades in the remaining 24 cards, and can't find any formulas that would handle this.

Comment: You must supply some effort on your own. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What do you know? What kind of method do you think is appropriate? Etc etc

Comment: i know the odds of having at least one spade in each hand are 1/3.   but this is different than the odds of each person having exactly one of the three available spades in the remaining 24 cards, and can't find any formulas that would handle this

Comment: Do you know the number of ways the cards can be distributed?

Comment: This appears to be a more careful statement of a problem [asked very recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738391/playing-cards-probability-question-help) by the same new user. @gman22:  You should try the approach outlined for you earlier.  Count all the possible outcomes, and then count the subset of these in which the three people get each one of three spades.  The ratio of the latter to the former is your probability.

Answer (score 0):

This just boils down to caclulating how many ways can three people end up with exactly one of three objects. Lets first calculate all possible outcomes, here I’m assuming you deal 8 at a time to each player:

# outcomes = $$\binom{24}{8}\binom{16}{8}\binom{8}{8} = 9,465,511,770$$

The logic behind this is how many ways can you choose 8 items from 24?, then after you pass those out how many ways can you choose 8 things from 16? And then multiply these together. I’m not using permutations because that would be overcounting. It doesn’t matter in what sequence each player recieves a spade, it only matters that they have it in a group of 8.

Now for the outcome we are interested in. We want each player to have exactly one of the remaining spades. This is the product of the following:

$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{21}{7}\binom{2}{1}\binom{15}{7}\binom{1}{1}\binom{7}{7} = 4,489,570,800$$

Then take the ratio to get the probability:

$P($ all three get exactly one spade $) = \frac{4,489,570,800}{9,465,511,770} = .4743$